# About page (site tour) still refers to FAQ and not the Help Center

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-completed

The text in at the bottom of the about page still points people to the FAQ and not the very nicely assembled Help Center.

[image: Visit the FAQ]

I'd put "Help Center" on the button, but something without FAQ would also be fine if you wanted a verb in the button text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure when this happened ([didn't seem to be specifically documented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)) but it did happen
(at least before December 2013):

[image: Find a question to answer, or ask your own | See new questions | Ask a question | Looking for more in-depth information on the site? Visit the Help Center]